# Failure to connect Debian NIS client to OpenSuse 12.1 server

Tags: debian, opensuse, nis

I'm trying to connect a Debian 7.0 client to a OpenSuse 12.1 server. The nisdomainname is correct, the /etc/group, /etc/passwd and /etc/shadown all have the +::: lines, ypbind connects, but the authentication, both via ssh or directly on the machine, fails. The log /var/log/auth.log on the Debian machine only shows that the authentication password failed. The NIS server works fine with other Opensuse machines.